# after clicking the cancel button close the popup window and redirect to parent window

Tags: 2013, javascript

I had a requirement in my code as follows

After click the cancel button in the sp model popup window it should be closed and redirect to the parent window.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
function openModall(pUrl) {
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(
     {
         url: pUrl,
         dialogReturnValueCallback: CloseCallback
     }
   );
}

function CloseCallback(result, returnValue) {
    if (result == SP.UI.DialogResult.OK) 
    {
        // some code
    }
    else if (result == SP.UI.DialogResult.cancel) {
        // Redirect here
    }
}
```

Comment: Exact solution i was going to provide +1

Comment: Glad to read it!

Answer (score 0):

```
window.close();
```

I think you mean redirecting to parent window. If you want to close the current popup window in back end, form/window is the parent.

```
onclick="window.open('http://google.com'); window.close();"
```

Comment: I tried but it is not working   <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Cancel" OnClientClick="window.close();" id="btnCancel"/>

Comment: Follow this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36458/ASP-NET-parent-page-partial-refresh-after-closing)

Comment: Actually am using sp model popup

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code given below:

Close the popup:

```
$('dialog id').dialog('close');
```

Provide the id of the popup @ dialog id and check.

Redirect to parent window:

```
window.parent.location.herf="http://www.google.com"
```

Comment: Thank you Mancy Desaee,finally i got solution,,,,,Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>window.frameElement.commitPopup();</script>");

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
onclick="window.open('http://msdn.com'); window.frameElement.commonModalDialogClose();"
```